# Extract Values of String Given preceeding substring Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract the values of the following strings to add them to their own cells.  The strings are the probabilites of seat being won in a constituency

Input 1

Chance of winningCON95%LAB5%LIB0%Green0%Reform0%OTH0%

Chance of winningLAB85%CON15%Reform0%LIB0%Green0%OTH0%

Desired Output - straight forward enough if the strings were all ordered the same, however the Party with the highest probability of winning is listed first

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR3lT.png)

I have tried some basic regex.

Comment: Please set up a spreadsheet with sample raw data entered where it will be in your real spreadsheet and results columns set up where you want them. Share the link, being sure to set the Share permission for the link to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" so that those here can access the sheet and test solutions. I can envision how to solve this, but the most efficient and effective way for me to share that solution is for you to share a sheet inside which I can work.

Comment: Please also indicate whether the percentages in the string will always be whole-number integers, or whether they may include decimal portions (e.g. 73.5, 94.75, etc.).

Comment: this can be done with one formula in one location for all results. If you are interested in seeing that solution, please provide the pieces I've requested above. If not, all the best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use separate `REGEXEXTRACT` to ignore the order.

#### Formula:

`B2` = `=ARRAYFORMULA(if($A2:$A <> "", REGEXEXTRACT($A2:$A, "CON([\d.]+%)"), ""))`

`C2` = `=ARRAYFORMULA(if($A2:$A <> "", REGEXEXTRACT($A2:$A, "LAB([\d.]+%)"), ""))`

`D2` = `=ARRAYFORMULA(if($A2:$A <> "", REGEXEXTRACT($A2:$A, "LIB([\d.]+%)"), ""))`

`E2` = `=ARRAYFORMULA(if($A2:$A <> "", REGEXEXTRACT($A2:$A, "Green([\d.]+%)"), ""))`

`F2` = `=ARRAYFORMULA(if($A2:$A <> "", REGEXEXTRACT($A2:$A, "Reform([\d.]+%)"), ""))`

`G2` = `=ARRAYFORMULA(if($A2:$A <> "", REGEXEXTRACT($A2:$A, "OTH([\d.]+%)"), ""))`

Formula above will extract the percentage (with decimal or not) regardless of the order. If it was in specific order, then 1 formula will suffice. But since it isn't, we need to separately search for them.

#### Sample:

[image: sample output]

I used `ARRAYFORMULA` so you don't need to copy the formula on all rows. Populating `A2:A` will automatically populate your `B:G` values. Formula is only needed in first row with data. It will propagate the values on other rows automatically.

Comment: Worked a treat, many thanks for your help, greatly appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @PhillFairclough. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer